# jQuery selector <select> in <tr> + css('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML below, I'm tring to select the `<select>` with `id= "g+anything"` in `<tr id='g2'>`.

```
<table>
     <tr id='g1><td>
         <select id="gm">
             <option value="1"></option>
             <option value="2"></option>
         </select>
         </td><td>
         <select id="gg">
             <option value="1"></option>
             <option value="2"></option>
         </select>
     </td>
     <tr id='g2><td>
         <select id="gm">
             <option value="1"></option>
             <option value="2"></option>
         </select>
         </td><td>
         <select id="gg">
             <option value="1"></option>
             <option value="2"></option>
         </select>
     </td>
 <table>
 <button id="button" ></button>
```

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {  
    $('tr#g2 select').css('pointer-events: none');
});
```

UPDATE: Sorry for the mistake, that's a small portion of my site.
I'm tring to adjust in readable.

Comment: what you mean by this id= "gare+anything" where is this id

Comment: @Kartikeya chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token " : "

Comment: Duplicate ids. Good luck with selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the css function wrong. Try the following:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {  
    $('tr#g2 select').css('pointer-events', 'none');
});
```